# How to make div element 100% using display flex in React?

Tags: css, flexbox

How to make the selected div element to be 100% in the inspect element tool in the picture below. I am using `display:flex` on `.dvPageNotFound` class and I want to apply `height:100%` on the `div` element inside it. If we put `display:flex` on parent element then all the child elements gets stretched by default, but here I don't get my child element stretched. I don't know why? I am using 12 column grid system same as `bootstrap 4` grid Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

HERE IS THE CODE -

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const PageNotFound = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dvPageNotFound d-flex">
        <div class='col-12'>
          <h1 className="heading-lg">Page Not Found</h1>
          <p className="my-3">The page you are looking for we coudn't found.</p>
          <Link to="/" className="btn btn-black">
            Back to Homepage
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PageNotFound;
```

Comment: use w-100 or equivalent class from bootstrap 4 to span full width

Comment: I want the div element which is the child element under d-flex class to apply height:100%

Comment: Also added col-12 class which give a width 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I added `height: 100vh` and added `m-auto` classes which we get from the 12 column grid.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const PageNotFound = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dvPageNotFound d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <div className="m-auto">
          <h1 className="heading-lg">Page Not Found</h1>
          <p className="my-3">The page you are looking for we coudn't found.</p>
          <Link to="/" className="btn btn-black">
            Back to Homepage
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PageNotFound;
```